# Counting total occurence of comma-seperated positive and negative numbers in a string

Tags: java, string, numbers

I am trying to implement the algorithm for the counting the number of numbers in the string which contains positive integers,negative integers,positive floating numbers and negative floating point numbers respectively.

String is like this::
String mystring = "-7.5,-1.43,3.4,43.5, -9954.88, 949.5, 1, 3, -45";

I am able to implement the code which counts the positive and negative integers such as

When I run this code,the count comes out to be  15 instead of 3. Can anyone please help me how to implement the logic to ignore positive and negative floating point numbers???

Thanks.

Comment: `return input.split(",\\s*").length;`

Comment: Java8? `return Arrays.stream(input.split(",")).map(Double::parseDouble).filter(e -> Math.abs(e) == e ? true : false).count();`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement this algorithm, you could try something like this:

```
public static int countIntegers(String input) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean sequenceStarted = false;
    boolean isInteger = false;
    boolean tailSpace = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c == ',') {
            //we got a delimiter; checking that the previous sequence is an integer
            if (sequenceStarted && (isInteger || tailSpace)) count++;
            sequenceStarted = false;
            isInteger = false;
            tailSpace = false;
        } else if (!sequenceStarted && c != ' ') {
            //ignoring all leading spaces
            sequenceStarted = true;
            //we got a digit, + or -; it means that number is started
            if (Character.isDigit(c) || (c == '+' || c == '-') 
                                 && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i + 1)))
                isInteger = true;
        } else if (sequenceStarted && !Character.isDigit(c)) {
            //the character is not a digit, but maybe it is a tail space?
            tailSpace = (isInteger || tailSpace) && c == ' ';
            isInteger = false;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This code takes into account leading and tailing spaces and counts only integers. For example, for the given string `String mystring = ", 4  ,+-7,  ,-,-7.5,-1.43,3.4,43.5, -9954.88 , r949, 1, 3, -45, 0.0, 5s, 7-, 2+2";` it prints `4`.

Of course, if you just want to count all integers in the string that may contain only digits, spaces, dots and commas, Java 8 solution is what you need:

```
String mystring = "-7.5,-1.43,3.4,43.5, -9954.88, 949.5, 1, 3, -45";
long count =
    // splitting your string by ","
    Arrays.stream(mystring.split(","))
        // converting each string to double
        .map(Double::parseDouble)
        // leaving only integers: if d is equal to Math.floor(d) then it must have an int value
        .filter(d -> Math.floor(d) == d && d != 0)
        .count();
System.out.println(count); //prints 3
```